# Blackberry simulator not creating COD file

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry-simulator

This is an answer to anyone having problems getting a program to appear in the Blackberry simulator or problems generating a COD file.

I have been programming in JAVA using the Eclipse IDE and my program was working fine in the BB simulator. After creating a new package and adding more class files to my project, I noticed that my changes were not being reflected in the simulator. After countless hours trying to solve the problem (cleaning, running clean.bat, deleting cod files, creating a new workspace, etc. - nothing worked) I just discovered an answer on a forum that solved my problem:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Eclipse-I-O-Error-Cannot-run-program-quot-jar-quot-CreateProcess/td-p/37701

I had 116 files in my project. I deleted two packages to get the number of classes under 100 and, voila, a new COD file was generated and my changes are reflected now in the Blackberry simulator. This is obviously a bug that RIM needs to address. I wasted days debugging this until I found a solution.

Hoping this helps someone with similar problems.

Comment: I think you could edit your question to describe your problem, and then add the answer you already provided as answer. Wait some days if someone else has another solution and if not (or if your answer is better), mark your answer as the accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while from my Blackberry days, but there are two things you should check:

- Check that you do not have a large class file. A single cod file is limited to 64K, so if a class file is more than 20-30K sometimes the compiler is not smart enough to organize the files in several code files.
- Compile using ant build file, see here http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs