# BlackBerry - Changes are not getting reflected in my app

Tags: deployment, build, blackberry

Suddenly my changes are not getting reflected when I run my app.

I have tried the following things.

1. Restarted the Eclipse and tried.
2. created a new Eclipse workspace.
3. Uninstall and installed the Blackberry JDE.
4. As I read ["Blackberry simulator not creating COD file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929363/blackberry-simulator-not-creating-cod-file), I have deleted some java files and images then tried.

Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your project is "Activated for BlackBerry" like this: [image: this screenshot]

Comment: Hi Orson,

Thank you for your reply.

Yes its activated only.

Comment: BlackBerry -> Erase Simulator Files -> Erase All ?

Answer (score 0):

Next best thing you can do is go to simulator folder in bb plugin and:

- delete < ProjectName >.* files
- run clean.bat

After that, if app will simply not load into simulator, do Alt+B (Project->Build Active BB Configuration) and see in Console (Alt+Shift+Q, C), if there was any errors during rapc execution.